# How can I detect a key press / button down event in XMonad?

Tags: x11, xorg, xmonad

I've tried to detect this manually by:

```
myHook :: Event -> X All
myHook e = do
  liftIO $ logToTmpFile $ show e
  pure $ All True
```

However on the keypress of `modm` (`hyper`/`windows`) it just shows:

```
PropertyEvent {ev_event_type = 28, ev_serial = 12080, ev_send_event = False, ev_event_display = Display 0x0000000000df2340, ev_window = 27262982, ev_atom = 353, ev_time = 20662387, ev_propstate = 0}
```

Which seems rather generic, different keys seem to also emit the same event.

---

Upon inspection of the XMonad source, it seems 'events' only occur for keystrokes that are 'registered' to be listened to.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605399/how-can-i-set-an-action-to-occur-on-a-key-release-in-xmonad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To register a 'keystroke':

```
myStartupHook :: X ()
myStartupHook = do
  XConf { display = dpy, theRoot = rootw } <- ask
  myKeyCode <- io $ (keysymToKeycode dpy xK_Super_R)
  io $ grabKey dpy (myKeyCode) anyModifier rootw True grabModeAsync grabModeAsync
```

And

```
myHook :: Event -> X All
myHook e = do
  liftIO $ logToTmpFile $ show e
  pure $ All True
```

And then add these to your `startupHook` and `handleEventHook` values in the config.

I see the following output:

```
KeyEvent {ev_event_type = 3, ev_serial = 2866, ev_send_event = False, ev_event_display = Display 0x0000000001217340, ev_window = 1056, ev_root = 1056, ev_subwindow = 25166105, ev_time = 4248223, ev_x = 1014, ev_y = 1038, ev_x_root = 1014, ev_y_root = 1038, ev_state = 64, ev_keycode = 134, ev_same_screen = True
```